# How to ignore null dates when sorting using django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-filter

Using [django-filter](https://github.com/alex/django-filter) I am able to set up a sort, and order by date.

But when I want to sort by a nullable date, I would like the null entries to always be at the bottom of the list. Is there any way to control or override this? I tried modifying the queryset of the view using extra:

```
    # following ensures no projects are at bottom of list
    if self.request.GET.get('o', None) == "-most_recent_project":
        queryset = queryset.extra(select={
            'most_recent_project_date_is_not_null': 'most_recent_project IS NOT NULL',
        },
                                  order_by=['most_recent_project_date_is_not_null', 'most_recent_project'],
        )
```

but it didn't work, I think django_filters overrides this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
if self.request.GET.get('o') == '-most_recent_project':
    queryset = queryset.filter(most_recent_project__isnull=False)
...
```

You can read about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Comment: well it doesn't answer my question, but it basically solves the problem although nothing I didn't know already. Thank you.

Comment: I thought on problem solving.